# How to create Thor::Group class variables

Tags: ruby, thor

I seem to be unable to get variables to work in Thor::Group. I've tried everything up to defining constants $CONFIG $STAGING_DIR but they just don't work.

```
class Package < Thor::Group
include Thor::Actions
attr_accessor :staging_dir, :config
argument :repo, :type => :string, :desc => "The repo to export"
desc "Testing 1.2.3..."

def test_meth
    uri = URI.parse(repo)
    if uri.kind_of?(URI::Generic)
        say "-- Repository seems to be a local directory", :cyan
        if File.exist? repo
            @config = YAML.load_file(repo + "/project.yaml")
            @staging_dir = "/var/tmp/pkg/stage/" + @config["project"]["name"]
            FileUtils.remove_dir @staging_dir if File.exists? @staging_dir
            empty_directory @staging_dir
            directory(repo, @staging_dir)
        end
    end
end

def failure
    puts @config
    puts @staging_dir
end

def self.source_root
    File.dirname(@staging_dir)
end


end
Package.start
```

./fubar /var/tmp/test/
-- Repository seems to be a local directory
nil
nil

Does anyone knows how to make a class variable accessible in Thor::Group?

Answer (score 1):

Just define some private methods.  Private methods are not automatically executed like regular methods in a Thor script.  The instance variable within the method evaluates the stuff you put on the right side of the ||= the first time the method is called.  The result is then returned.  Thereafter, it simply returns the value. So your code would be re-written as follows:

```
class Package < Thor::Group
  include Thor::Actions
  attr_accessor :staging_dir, :config
  argument :repo, :type => :string, :desc => "The repo to export"
  desc "Testing 1.2.3..."

  def test_meth
      uri = URI.parse(repo)
      if uri.kind_of?(URI::Generic)
          say "-- Repository seems to be a local directory", :cyan
          if File.exist? repo
              FileUtils.remove_dir staging_dir if File.exists? staging_dir
              empty_directory staging_dir
              directory(repo, staging_dir)
          end
      end
  end

  def failure
      puts config
      puts staging_dir
  end

  def self.source_root
      File.dirname(staging_dir)
  end

  private

  def config
    @config ||= YAML.load_file(repo + "/project.yaml")
  end

  def staging_dir
    @staging_dir ||= "/var/tmp/pkg/stage/" + @config["project"]["name"]
  end

end
Package.start
```